# Hook_menu() and its page callback: how to redirect users on a condition?

Tags: 7, redirection, routes

I'm trying to redirect users from an existing path in Drupal 7 to another existing path. I want to implement the following rule:

`comment/reply/123` should redirect to `node/123#comment-form`

But

`comment/reply/123/456` should NOT redirect anywhere and just go where it goes.

I've tried to implement this behavior with hook_menu(), but here's the problem. When I register an item with the path `'comment/reply/%'` that corresponds to `comment/reply/123`, it automatically includes paths like `comment/reply/123/456`. I know that's intended and changed my code to include this case, but can't figure out how to redirect users only when they hit `comment/reply/123`. Here's my code:

```
function mymodule_menu()
{
    $items = array();
    $items['comment/reply/%/%'] = array(
        'title' => 'bla',
        'page callback' => '_mymodule_redirect',
        'page arguments' => array(2, 3),
        'access callback' => TRUE,
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );
    return $items;
}

function _mymodule_redirect($node_id, $comment_id)
{
    if(isset($comment_id))
    {
        return; //I want to just go to comment/reply/123/456 here, but it gives me a blank page
    }
    else
    {
        drupal_goto('node/' . $node_id . '#comment-form');
    }
}
```

So how do I go where I want to go?

**Update:** This is my final solution: I now use `hook_menu_alter()` to rewrite an already defined link and `comment_reply()` to serve standard comment form.

```
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) 
{
  $items['comment/reply/%node']['page callback'] = '_mymodule_redirect';
}

function _mymodule_redirect($node, $pid = NULL)
{
    if(isset($pid))
    {
         return comment_reply($node, $pid);
    }
    else
    {
        drupal_goto(drupal_get_path_alias('node/' . $node->nid), array('fragment' => 'comment-form'), 301);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood correctly, you want to serve the comment reply page provided by core when your condition is met.

If that's the case, you just need to use the [`comment_reply()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!comment!comment.pages.inc/function/comment_reply/7) function:

```
if (isset($comment_id)) {
  return comment_reply(node_load($node_id), $comment_id);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are altering a `hook_menu` item that an existing module defines, use [`hook_menu_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7). You will receive all menu items by reference, and you can alter the necessary menu items as necessary.

In a `hook_menu()` implementation, if you define `example` path, `http://example.com/example`, `http://example.com/example/foo`, `http://example.com/example/foo/bar...` and so on will have the same page callback and other properties. However, if you define `http://example.com/example/foo/mine`, that page will use the explicit definition of `example/foo/mine`. There is a negotiation with `MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK` too.

PS: If you are trying to redirect comment pages to their node paths, try [this module](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/Ayesh/1578662).

Comment: Thanks, I'm now using hook_menu_alter(). I can't mark 2 replies as 'Answers', but your reply was useful and I gave you a +1.